# php array convertido em json não mantém ordem no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho um array com o seguinte formato:

```
$vetor = array(

   1=>array(
      pt-BR => array(
       'pergunta1' => 'pergunta 1 em texto'
       'resposta1' => 'resposta 1 em texto'
         )
      )
   3=>array(
      pt-BR => array(
       'pergunta3' => 'pergunta 3 em texto'
       'resposta3' => 'resposta 3 em texto'
         )
      )
);
```

Estou tentando gravar esse array numa coluna dinâmica 'json' no mysql 5.7.
Como consigo manter a ordem colocando a pergunta 3 antes da 1 e manter essa ordem?

Comment: Como assim "3 antes da 1" e "manter essa ordem"?

Comment: Ordem decrescente?

Comment: A ordem que eu definir ele. Ele não mantém a ordem e ordena de forma crescente.

Comment: Porque é um *array*. Se você precisa dele ordenado, irá ter que ordená-lo quando for utilizar os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar um array de forma decrescente você deve utilizar a função [`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ksort.php), mas esta função manterá as chaves originais. Caso queira garantir essa nova ordem, você pode utilizar [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php) para obter uma cópia do array com chaves novas.

```
$vetor = [
    1 => [
        'pt-BR' => [
            'pergunta1' => 'pergunta 1 em texto',
            'resposta1' => 'resposta 1 em texto'
        ]
    ],
    3 => [
        'pt-BR' => [
            'pergunta3' => 'pergunta 3 em texto',
            'resposta3' => 'resposta 3 em texto'
        ]
    ]
];

krsort($vetor);// ordena de forma decrescente
$vetor = array_values($vetor);// extrai os valores do array e cria novas chaves para ele
var_dump($vetor);

$vetor = json_encode($vetor);// json na ordem desejada
var_dump($vetor);
```

O resultado do primeiro `var_dump` nesse caso será:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["pt-BR"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["pergunta3"]=>
      string(19) "pergunta 3 em texto"
      ["resposta3"]=>
      string(19) "resposta 3 em texto"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["pt-BR"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["pergunta1"]=>
      string(19) "pergunta 1 em texto"
      ["resposta1"]=>
      string(19) "resposta 1 em texto"
    }
  }
}
```

E o segundo `var_dump` após o `json_encode` retornará:

```
string(161) "[{"pt-BR":{"pergunta3":"pergunta 3 em texto","resposta3":"resposta 3 em texto"}},{"pt-BR":{"pergunta1":"pergunta 1 em texto","resposta1":"resposta 1 em texto"}}]"
```

Comment: Por favor, veja [answer], incluia um exemplo mínimo e verificável na sua resposta. Respostas contendo apenas link não são muito úteis, devido ao link poder ficar OFF

Comment: O problema é na hora de gravar no banco, gazer is to não garante a ordem quando gravado

Comment: Então a solução é você salvar no banco de dados em ordem crescente mesmo, e utilizar essa função que te mostrei quando for exibir os dados.

Comment: Eu digitei pelo celular e cortou o texto, é o seguinte, não compensa ajustar, quando ele usar json_encode para gravar no banco a ordenação talvez não seja preservada e no momento de ler isto também se perde as vezes, fora que para iterar (for, while, etc) estar ordenado não faz muita diferença se for usar `$i++`, como eu disse na minha resposta.

Comment: Então a solução seria criar uma cópia do array com novas chaves antes do json_encode, isso garantiria a nova ordem ao inserir no banco de dados.
E quando for exibir os dados resgatados do banco de dados bastaria utilizar um foreach.

Answer (score 0):

**Não importa** a ordem que é gravada, no momento de decodificar (quando faz o `SELECT` e depois usa `json_decode`) é **provável que a ordem se perca novamente**, não é preciso se preocupar com o momento do "salvamento", se preocupe no momento depois *"de decodificar"* para exibir, você pode resolver no momento da leitura facilmente no `for`

```
$obj = json_decode($linha['dadosjsonnobanco'], true);

//Pega a maior chave no seu array
$higher = max(array_keys($obj));

for ($i = $higher; $i >= 0; $i--) {
     if (empty($obj[$i])) continue; //Se não existir um item pula para o proximo

     var_dump($obj[$i]);
}
```

Veja que ao invés de usar `++` eu inverti, está `--`, assim você começa pelo numero maior, ele começa por exemplo no 3, então vai para 2 e como o 2 não existe ele dispara o `continue;`, então vai para o 1 depois para o `0`, como o `0` não existe ele termina o `for`